# How to configuration Modsecurity logs?

Tags: apache, mod-security, mod-security2

I think it's too much detail.  I installed it on windows 7 and using apache server.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F55Yp.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V09JL.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg7pd.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHjKH.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF9dw.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CRS developer here. It's true that the logs by default contain a lot of information. Maybe you can be helped by using JSON as a log format. You can do this by adding:

```
SecAuditLogFormat JSON
```

to your mod_security.conf file. (Note: I have no Windows experience so I don't know the exact name and location of the config file).

Then, the log will contain one JSON object per line for every logged event. You can use the `jq` utility to pretty-print the JSON or to select only the interesting parts.

For instance, if you want to see only the matched rule messages, you can use `jq` like this:

```
curl 'https://sandbox.coreruleset.org/?test=posix_uname(123)' | jq .audit_data.messages

[
  "Warning. Matched phrase \"posix_uname\" at ARGS:test. [file \"/etc/modsecurity.d/owasp-crs/rules/REQUEST-933-APPLICATION-ATTACK-PHP.conf\"] [line \"294\"] [id \"933150\"] [msg \"PHP Injection Attack: High-Risk PHP Function Name Found\"] [data \"Matched Data: posix_uname found within ARGS:test: posix_uname(123)\"] [severity \"CRITICAL\"] [ver \"OWASP_CRS/3.3.2\"] [tag \"modsecurity\"] [tag \"application-multi\"] [tag \"language-php\"] [tag \"platform-multi\"] [tag \"attack-injection-php\"] [tag \"paranoia-level/1\"] [tag \"OWASP_CRS\"] [tag \"capec/1000/152/242\"]",
  "Warning. Operator GE matched 5 at TX:anomaly_score. [file \"/etc/modsecurity.d/owasp-crs/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf\"] [line \"93\"] [id \"949110\"] [msg \"Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 5)\"] [severity \"CRITICAL\"] [ver \"OWASP_CRS/3.3.2\"] [tag \"modsecurity\"] [tag \"application-multi\"] [tag \"language-multi\"] [tag \"platform-multi\"] [tag \"attack-generic\"]",
  "Unconditional match in SecAction. [file \"/etc/modsecurity.d/crs-demo-setvar.conf\"] [line \"11\"] [id \"100000\"] [tag \"modsecurity\"]",
  "Warning. Operator GE matched 5 at TX:inbound_anomaly_score. [file \"/etc/modsecurity.d/owasp-crs/rules/RESPONSE-980-CORRELATION.conf\"] [line \"91\"] [id \"980130\"] [msg \"Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Inbound Score: 5 - SQLI=0,XSS=0,RFI=0,LFI=0,RCE=0,PHPI=5,HTTP=0,SESS=0): individual paranoia level scores: 5, 0, 0, 0\"] [ver \"OWASP_CRS/3.3.2\"] [tag \"modsecurity\"] [tag \"event-correlation\"]"
]
```